# Open and tile windows with shell script

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint, tiling-wm

I cannot find this answer anywhere. No idea where to start.

How do I open let's say `nemo`. I know I can set the window size using `-geometry`. But how do I tile it on a specific monitor/quadrant?

I'm making a shell script that sets up a work space for a given directory.

Comment: use [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/)

Comment: @IporSircer Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an odd "hacky" way to do it. That is to simulate the keyboard shortcut for tiling on the window (ie `super+Left`) using `xdotool`.

```
# Launch the program (ie nemo)
gtk-launch nemo

# Wait 0.5 seconds for the window to get open
# and then get the window id using xdotool 
sleep 0.5
$WINDOW_ID=`xdotool search --name Home` # "Home" is the title of the nemo window

# Simulate a tiling shortcut (tile left)
xdotool windowactivate $WINDOW_ID
xdotool key super+Left
```

By all means I hate my own answer. It's very hacky and dirty and not flexable whatso ever. But none the less, does what it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this script: https://github.com/kstenschke/xmchord/blob/master/bin/actions/utils/splitDesk.sh
It originally implemented tiling, i extended it to work on My setup of three Monitors.

Comment: Thanks for the script, it's a really great base to work from.  I like to map window positions to Super numberpad and I think your script will be easily adapted to this